# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed but no tcp socket reset

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, c3p0

My app got the error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor281.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
```

When my app sees that error it automatically retry the operation. But when I did a tcpdump and I don't see any new tcp connection is created at that time. It looks like the same tcp connection is used. So why I get the exception? My app uses c3p0 connection pool and I set c3p0 to test connection before check in. Is there any settings to mysql driver or c3p0 to get around this problem?

Comment: Closing a pooled connection only returns it to the pool.  No new server connection would be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

testConnectionOnCheckin alone is insufficient to ensure that Connections don't time out in the pool. if the pool is not very busy, Connections may remained checked-in and idle indefinitely. testConnectionOnCheckin should be combined with idleConnectionTestPeriod, so that idle Connections are periodically verified as well.

see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

good luck!